# c++ parameter as const T vs const T&

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, compiler-optimization

suppose `SomeDataStruct` is "huge", will a modern compiler produce equivalent and therefore equally efficient code in the following two cases?

```
1) void fooByValue(const SomeDataStruct data);   

2) void fooByReference(const SomeDataStruct& data);
```

if equivalent, which idiom is "preferable", why?

please note that this question is similar to this one:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/372105/is-passing-arguments-as-const-references-premature-optimization

but not identical, since i here use "`const`" in both functions; in the mentioned link, `fooByValue` is just

```
1) void fooByValue(SomeDataStruct data);
```

edit: suppose `SomeDataStruct` type does not have any copy constructor.

Comment: They are not equivalent. In case (1) you told the compiler to make a copy; in case (2) you didn't.  Copies are a visible side-effect.  The function could change the original and expect a compare with the copy to fail.

Comment: @ㄈㄟㄈㄟ The qualifier const is redundand in this declaration  void fooByValue(const SomeDataStruct data); The compiler will pass an object of the structure by value making a "huge" copy.

Comment: @RichardCritten since data is const in both cases, the compiler may optimize that copy away...?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow cant the compiler take advantage of the constantness to avoid making a copy?

Comment: Technically, it's up to the compiler and its strategies for optimisation.   But, generally speaking, passing something by value means creating a copy of whatever is passed, whereas passing a reference only passes a bit of information that identifies where the object is in memory (akin to a pointer, possibly even a pointer behind the scenes).  So passing a larger structure by value will tend to be more expensive than passing a reference.   If passing by value, BTW, using `const` does not give any advantages in terms of efficiency.

Comment: The "make a huge copy" is a good choice for a data sink parameter.  Otherwise, a `const&` for a parameter that *cannot be nullptr*, or `const*` for a parameter that may be valid or may be nullptr.  Only use a `unique_ptr` when transferring ownership to the function.  Only use `shared_ptr` if you really have to, because due to federated ownership is effectively a global (albeit limited to the shared owners).  The non-const `&` is good for a parameter that will be modified (i.e., mutable).

Comment: @UriRaz Reread one more my comment. I said nothing about passing by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> suppose SomeDataStruct is "huge", will a modern compiler produce equivalent and therefore equally efficient code in the following two cases?

It depends on the compiler, how you defined the object, what is happening to the object in the function. Lets find out what gcc does on x86-64 Linux. Take a look at the following code:

```
struct big_
{
    unsigned long w,x,y,z;
    int pos;
};

unsigned long byval(const big_ big)
{
    auto y = big.z;
    y += big.y;
    y += big.x;
    y += big.w;
    return y;
}

unsigned long byref(const big_& big)
{
    auto y = big.z;
    y += big.y;
    y += big.x;
    y += big.w;
    return y;
}
```

Compiling it with `g++ -std=c++17 -O3` gives me the following assembly [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/bvnxv9):

```
byval(big_):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+24]
        add     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+32]
        add     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+16]
        add     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        ret
byref(big_ const&):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+16]
        add     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+24]
        add     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        add     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        ret
```

What can we see in the above code?

The arguments to first function, `byval` are passed on the stack. The arguments to the second function are passed via the register `rdi` (See calling conventions for your OS to find out why). Passing anything via register is always faster than passing on stack because registers are closer to the `cpu` while stack is somewhere in the cache or ram. Hence passing by reference is better here. If you have a small object (8 bytes), passing it by value is better because it will get passed via the register anyways. Passing by stack only happens when your object is so big that it can't fit inside a register.

Another thing we can see is that `byval` has a parameter which is not `const`. The compiler just dropped it.

> since i here use "const" in both functions;

This doesn't matter as you can see from the explanations above.

> `void fooByValue(SomeDataStruct data);`
> edit: suppose SomeDataStruct type does not have any copy constructor.

If you didn't write a copy constructor, that doesn't mean the compiler can not generate one for you implicitly. But let's assume you deleted it. So now you cannot copy it and if you try, your code will not compile. However, if you have defined a move constructor, you can *move* it.

```
void fn()
{
    fooByValue( std::move(data) ); // no copy
}
```

---

Using `const` will not change your code's performance. `const` is like a contract between you and the compiler. When you mark something as `const`, the compiler will not allow you to change it. If you somehow change it, it will result in undefined behaviour. I suggest you go and read this article by Arthur O'Dwyer on this topic [const is a contract.](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/01/03/const-is-a-contract/)

Comment: your example of a "big" object is not representative for what a heavy copy object will be. Try with an object like `std::vector` where a copy is really expensive and passing by value vs passing by reference is a huge performance difference.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the point i tried to make. The performance difference is there, and the bigger / complex the object is, the higher will be the performance penalty. I just wanted to keep the answer simple and make a point without introducing too much complexity.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see how you made your point. You do indeed say in the beginning that "it matters" but then you give just one example: where it doesn't matter that much and talk about passing on stack vs register, but not about the other side. In the case of `vector` e.g. you need to do a lot of extra work: allocate memory, copy objects and it's done with exception safety grantee which further makes the algorithm slower. And someone reading your answer would be clueless about this other side of the coin from "it depends how you define the object" you vaguely alluded in the beginning.

Comment: What you say is true, yes. But I attempted to answer the question in the context of what was asked, which is just about paramater passing (ref vs value). In case of vector, almost the same thing will happen (passing on stack vs register). Other things will also happen, new allocation, constructor calls etc, but they will happen on the "caller" side, not in the "callee". Also that would blow the assembly out of proportion making it really difficult to get the basic point across. But I think I understand what you mean and I will expand teh answer to include these details.

Answer (score 0):

A top-level `const` (not behind a pointer/reference) has no effect in a declaration.

```c
// Even if the declaration uses const:
void fooByValue(const SomeDataStruct data);

// The definition without `const` is still considered a valid definition for that declaration.
// It's not a different overload!
// (this oddity is inherited from C, where overloading is a compiler error but this was always allowed)
void fooByValue(SomeDataStruct data)
{
   data.member = 0;
}
```

So the compiler is forced to ignore the `const` and has to assume the parameter might be modified --> a copy is necessary.
However the compiler might still optimize out the copy if the original copied-from variable isn't used after the function call.

The relevant portion of the C++ standard is 9.3.3.5 Functions:

> The type of a function is determined using the following rules. [..] After producing the list of parameter types, any top-level cv-qualifiers modifying a parameter type are deleted when forming the function type.

Comment: " has to assume the parameter might be modified" that's not true.